# RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint

Tags: spring

I'm having a problem with some of the links on my web application on netbeans. The web app has spring mvc and spring security implemented.

So basically, I have a link on one of the pages

```
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<h3 align="#center">You can login <a href="login.jsp">here</a>.</h3>
</td>
```

Then when I click "here", I get an error: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

The logs are as follows:

```
14:45:34,255 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:176 - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/login.jsp'; to: '/login.jsp'
14:45:34,255 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:183 - Candidate is: '/login.jsp'; pattern is /**; matched=true
14:45:34,255 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:351 - /login.jsp at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@a3d369'
14:45:34,255 DEBUG DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource:178 - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/login.jsp'; to: '/login.jsp'
14:45:34,255 DEBUG DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource:196 - Candidate is: '/login.jsp'; pattern is /; matched=false
14:45:34,255 DEBUG DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource:196 - Candidate is: '/login.jsp'; pattern is /login.jsp*; matched=true
14:45:34,255 DEBUG ChannelProcessingFilter:101 - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /login.jsp; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
14:45:34,255 DEBUG RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint:65 - Redirecting to: 
14:45:34,271 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:176 - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/'; to: '/'
```

If you notice, my app loses the url. It was able to match the url but then with the RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint, it's redirected to a blank url.

Any suggestions to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you redirect to different url in your controller .

for eg:

```
 return "redirect:/page";
```

where "page" is the direct name of page you want to navigate, you should use redirect in case you are redirecting to other mapping in your controller.

instead you should go for

```
 return "/page";
```